# acces to file using threads on python

Tags: python, multithreading, file

I have a txt file and I need to acces the file using threads on python.

`file.txt`:

```
line 1 data_1
line 2 data_2
...
line n data_n
```

Each thread loops 1000 lines. For example:

- thread_1 from 1 to 1000
- thread_2 from 1001 to 2000,
- ...

So to do that I have created 100 threads and each thread opens the file and uses it. My question is what is faster:

- Each thread opens the file
- Open the file one time and share it between all threads

Comment: I think having 100 threads read from the same file is a bit overkill

Comment: so each thread open the file

Comment: Load the file into a list and then process it

Comment: yes, but in this cas what is best shar the list

Comment: @everyone: it means loading 1000000 lines. Depending the size of lines it might waste memory...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Well OP didn't specify how large n was and lines isn't exactly a metric.

Comment: i have exactly 1000000 on my file

Comment: What is the faster? Probably not use so many threads... But what is the bottleneck that caused you to multithread the processing: disk io, network io, remote processing, memory, or CPU?

Comment: time because it's taking a lot of time to finish looping file whene i run 300M line

Comment: Hi can you help me